# Importing FITS files with Mathematica 11.3, bug?

Tags: import, fits-format

With Mathematica 11.2 I could import [this](https://data.sdss.org/sas/dr12/boss/lss/galaxy_DR12v5_CMASS_South.fits.gz) FITS file without problems in about 20-30 seconds using:

```
Import["filename.fits.gz", "TableData"]
```

With Mathematica 11.3 it failed after trying for 300 seconds.

Comment: I can't test it because I don't have 11.3, but I can confirm that it works on 11.2; this looks like a problem you should report to Wolfram Support.

Comment: It seems you can workaround it by ```Import["filename.fits.gz", "Table"]```